# Custom JsonConfiguration in Spring Rest

Tags: json, spring-mvc, kotlin

I am returning a `@Serializable` object from a Spring HTTP response. It is properly serialized to JSON, just as intended, the code roughly looks like this:

```
@Serializable
@SerialName("example")
data class Example (...): BaseExample(...)

@GetMapping("/path")
fun getExample(): Example = Example(...)
```

The object is a member of a class hierarchy, so I want the response to contain the serial name in the field `type`, so I want to provide a custom `JsonConfiguration` with `classDiscriminator = "type"`. How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I was able to solve it with a manual serialization:

```
@GetMapping("/path", produces=[MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun getExample(): String {
    val json = Json(JsonConfiguration(classDiscriminator = "type"))
    val result = ...
    return json.stringify(Example.serializer(), result)
}
```

So will stick to this way unless there's a more elegant solution.